# Want to take data from Power BI dataflow based on roles

Tags: powerbi, dataflow

I have created a Dataflow in power bi service. Now my client's requirements is that they want to take the data from the dataflow as per the roles. There is a user table where roles are already defined. My question is that without the relation between tables, how I am supposed to filter the data from all the tables? Is it possible at all? Or how can I make relationship of the tables in dataflow? Or any alternate procedure to take the data from dataflow as per the roles. Help me pls. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your data supports it, for example some sort of mapping between the user and the data they are allowed to see, you will need to use [`Row Level Security`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls) to restrict what the end users see in the report. You will make the relationship between your dataflow and mapping table in Power BI, not the dataflow.

If you mean restricting access to the data in the dataflow based on their role, for example the user creates a report it only loads what they are allowed to see, then this functionality is not supported.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, Jonee and Andrey for quick response.  Is there any alternate way to resolve my requirements?

Comment: it would have to be a none Power BI option, SQL Server supports RLS on tables https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Okay. Thank you, Jonee.